# Space character within symbol literals

Tags: kdb

I need to query a database which contains names of companies. I have list of around 50 names, for which i have to get the data. But I am unable to write a query using in command as there spaces in a name which are not being recognized. ex

```
select from sales where name in (`Coca Cola, `Pepsi)
```

This is giving me an error as 'Cola' is not being recognized. Is there a way to write such a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces between the strings cause the interpreter to get confused. The `$() casts the list of characters to symbols.

```
q)t:([] a:1 2 3; name:`$("coca cola";"pepsi";"milk"))

q)select from t where name in `$("coca cola";"pepsi")
a name
-----------
1 coca cola
2 pepsi
```

You may also want to be careful of casing and either use consistently lower or upper case else that would cause unexpected empty results:

```
q)select from t where name in `$("Coca Cola";"Pepsi")
a name
------

q)select from t where upper[name] in upper `$("Coca Cola";"Pepsi")
a name
-----------
1 coca cola
2 pepsi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the following:

```
select from sales where name in `$("Coca Cola";"Pepsi")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried using this, it doesn't give any error, but the query is returning zero results, whereas I know there are entries in the database.

Comment: what type is the name column?